# Posting data to php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

```
        <html>
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var submit_value = $(this).val();
                jQuery.post
                (


                );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="php page" id="the-form">
       Name <input type="text" name="name" > <br/>
           Number <input type="text" name="number" > <br/>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit">submit</button>
          </form>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I write to jQuery.post to send the data from the form to a php page, I tried some posibilities but when I clicked submit the php page responded "No value". I don't have to change anything at the php page just in this script.

Comment: Everything's here... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I also tried this:
$( "#the-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
 

  event.preventDefault();
 
 
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='Name']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );
 
 
  var posting = $.post( url, { Nev: term } );
 
  
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});

Comment: You don't need Javascript at all to read post data in PHP.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Where's the php code that sends `no value`? Add the  ajax code used to question also so it is readable

Answer (score 2):

Your references are off

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
```

This will observe your **submit button**, not the form. So when you get to this

```
$(this).val();
```

It's looking at your submit button (which has no value), not your form data. Instead, you should grab the form and observe the `submit` event and then [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the data

```
$("#the-form").on( "submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    jQuery.post('your/url.php', data, function(resp) {
        //Do something with the response here
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are using Firefox/Chrome you can inspect what's happening on the POST (Developer Tools -> Network). Perhaps showing a screenshot with the request you send and the relevant PHP code could help to help you.

Comment: That is the problem because I don't know the php code, I only know that I must send a json, and the variable name json, something like $_POST['json'];

I also tried another version but it's still not working, not even sending something:
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "php page"
type: "POST"
data: {
Name: $(#"Name").val(),
Number: $(#"Number").val()
},
dataType: "JSON",
succes: function (jsonStr){
$("#result").text(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
}
});
});
});

</script>